# xterm error information after crash

Tags: redirect, stderr, tcsh, xterm, tee

I'm running a TCL based shell on xterm from tcsh with tee into a log file (nice mixup :) )
At some point the session crashes, I can see the Fatal Error message for a brief moment before the xterm closes and than it's gone.
How can I get a hold on the crash information from the xterm session?
Trying to add & to the tee pipe ( ... |& tee -i ...) prevent me from even starting the xterm and it is needless to say the log contains nothing I can use.
Is there some place the information I'm looking for (the crash report\ fatal error message) in stored automatically?
Is there a way to force this debug information into a file?
One more thing - I don't have root access, so `dnsmasq.log` is out of my reach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the command-line option [`-hold`](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#OPTIONS:-hold) even without modifying the script.  Add this resource to your X resources (preferably to an xterm app-defaults file):

```
*hold: true
```

That makes each xterm act as if you ran it using

```
xterm -hold
```

because the command-line options are handled by setting X resource values.  Since the window doesn't go away, you can select/paste from it.

If you are not really using xterm, but some imitator, of course, you're out of luck.

Comment: Excellent, preventing the xterm from closing didn't come up my mind - was too busy looking for ways of redirecting the stderr. Great answer!